# Change icon color in title bar & status bar in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm driving myself nuts trying to figure out how to change the color of these icons in VSCode. Is it possible? I'm sure I'm missing something obvious. Anyone know how to do so?

[image: VS Code Icons]

[image: VS Code Icons]

Comment: These icons seem to have the same black color across multiple light themes. Therefore, I don't think the color of these icons is customizable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use extension [Custom CSS and JS Loader](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=be5invis.vscode-custom-css)

And use the extra style

```css
.codicon { color: red; }
```

You can color each individual icon by using the specific name class like:

```css
.codicon-split-horizontal:before { color: green; }
```

Use **Help** > **Toggle Developer Tools** to find out the class to use by locating the UI part with the top left arrow.

If the icon is an SVG it is also possible but you have to find the correct selector to change the color inside that SVG as used in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

VS Code migrated icons to a font in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/78889 which now allows for colour customisations of the icons, released in VS Code 1.39 (September 2019).

Set the following in settings.json

```json
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "icon.foreground": "#ff0000"
    }
```

In your first screenshot, a few of the editor action icons are contributed by the GitLens extension. One of those icons does not change colour on this setting, so I have raised the issue https://github.com/gitkraken/vscode-gitlens/issues/3206. Apart from that, all icons change colour with this setting:

[image]